# How to replace Pi Zero 2 W Buster onboard wifi with USB WiFi

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, pi-zero-w-2

I have a Pi Zero 2 W running Raspbian Buster where I need to disable the onboard WiFi, wlan0, and use a USB WiFi dongle. How do I make wlan1 join my WiFi network?

I have tried various approaches, but so far the USB WiFi (wlan1) always fails to join the network.  Once I can get wlan1 to join the network, I plan to disable the built in WiFi (wlan0) by adding to /boot/config.txt: `dtoverlay=disable-wifi`

Currently, I've changed my files in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ to be:

/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan1

```
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

My /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file contains:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=US

network={
    ssid="<my SSID>"
    psk=<my psk>
}
```

The ifconfig command returns:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 13  bytes 1756 (1.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13  bytes 1756 (1.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet <XXXX>  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast <XXXX>
        inet6 <XXXX>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:5f:01:49:ca:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 765  bytes 57373 (56.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 556  bytes 82690 (80.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0c:43:00:1e:62  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iwconfig returns (FYI, I have turned off power management for the WiFi):

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"<My SSID>"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: <XXXX>   
          Bit Rate=14.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:95  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`sudo systemctl status networking.service` returns:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-12-19 15:52:17 EST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
    Process: 418 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 418 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 229ms

Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi wpa_supplicant[460]: rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi wpa_supplicant[460]: Could not read interface wlan1 flags: No such device
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi wpa_supplicant[460]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan1' UP
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi wpa_supplicant[460]: wlan1: Failed to initialize driver interface
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi ifup[455]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 120: cannot create /dev/stderr: No such device or address
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi ifup[447]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi ifup[418]: ifup: failed to bring up wlan1
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 19 15:52:17 mypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: @Milliways Not really, as I have wpa_supplicant working, I just want to disable the built in wifi device and replace it with an external usb wifi dongle with better range.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Much simpler than I thought. In the file `/boot/config.txt`, I added the following lines:

```
# Disable onboard WiFi
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
```

That's it. My USB WiFi dongle became wlan0 and was configured by the system as the onboard WiFi would have been.